# Notify my my ViewModels that an async event is done

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm, windows-phone, inotifypropertychanged

So here is the scenario. I have a button on which I start downloading data. When my method is done I want all my viewModels to be notified, without the need to enter the views, and to fill their properties properly with the data downloaded. How to achieve this painless?

```
private ICommand loadDataCommand;

public MyViewModel()
{
    this.loadDataCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.LoadDataAction);
}

public ICommand LoadDataCommand
{
    get
    {
        return this.loadDataCommand;
    }
}

private void LoadDataAction(object p)
{
    this.MyViewModelDataSource.Clear();

    foreach (MyT mt in GlobalThings.MyTypeCollection)
    {
        this.MyViewModelDataSource.Add(tt);
    }
}
```

So this is my ViewModel and the command that is supposed to fill the data, that I wrote, but I cant call it when my download method ends, because I need to make an instance of my ViewModel and I dont want to.. Maybe some kind of notification to the viewModels?

*EDIT:
I did what you suggested and here is the result:*

**ViewModel**

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    Messenger.Default.Register<MyType>
    (
        this,
        (action) => ReceiveMessage(action)
    );
}

private void ReceiveMessage(MyType action)
{
    this.MyViewModelDataSource.Clear();

    foreach (MyT mt in GlobalDeclarations.MyTypeCollection)
    {
        this.MyViewModelDataSource.Add(tt);
    }
}
```

**The class where the download method is in it i add at the end:**

```
    Messenger.Default.Send<MyType>(GlobalDeclarations.MyTypeCollection);
}
```

but it tells me:

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a
>   different thread

on this line: "this.MyViewModelDataSource.Clear();"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can await in your method and put the rest of the implementation under it. Doing so will await the statement to be executed and then start with processing the rest of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I have just read :- `because I need to make an instance of my ViewModel and I dont want to.. Maybe some kind of notification to the viewModels?`

Actually If you are using `MVVM light toolkit` then you will see You will have a Class `ViewModelLocator` that is responsible for giving you your `viewmodel` objects. As it register your viewmodel and always provide you previous object of Viewmodel. It is basicaly `IOC container`.

So whenever you try to access the some Viewmodel through Viewmodellocator say : - `ViewmodelLocator.MainViewmodel` then it will always return you previously created Viewmodel Object. So just read little bit about it. I think you are not getting the working of`MVVM`.

after above implementation :-

I think there are two ways for that :-

1) You can use the MessangerClass of the MVVM light library.

2) create a static class that hold this downloaded data. Use this static class in all your viewmodels( is suggested this after thinking about your requirement) because you want to update all the viewmodels with the same data.

Usage of messenger is very easy :- 
You can send your data through messenger also.

Send:-

```
Messenger.Default.Send<YourDataObjectClass>( msg );
```

Register to recieve:-

```
Messenger.Default.Register<YourDataObjectClass>
( 
     this, 
     ( action ) => ReceiveMessage( action ) 
);

private object ReceiveMessage( YourDataObjectClass action )
{
  // do your update
}
```

hope it help you..

Comment: So I .Send<T>() my global MyTypeCollection object in the end of the download method? But this registering thing is it made in the constructor of the ViewModel?

Comment: Any idea why in the ReceiveMessage method when i try to insert some code it tells me:

"An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))"

even when I put it in

Application.Current.Resources.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => ...);

Comment: @V.G. I have used the above mentioned code.in many projects. never got this exception. May be something else is wrong. Project target, or debug configuration etc.

Comment: Maybe its because this code is in the ViewModel and the VM constructor is called when I open the view, because of the bindings?

Comment: VM constructor will be called only firsttime the VM is creating, not everytime you request for VM, because in your way, previous data can't be persistent.

Comment: are you using MVVM pattern ?